# SQL Server atomic increment

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, concurrency

I need to update several rows of one of my tables as an atomic operation.

The update concerns incrementing some values in int columns of certain rows. I need to increment values in several rows as a single action.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answering this question for me comes down to answering the following two:

- If I use LINQ to SQL, how do I achieve the atomicity of the increment
  operation (do I use transaction, or is there a better way)?
- Are stored procedures executed atomically (in case I invoke the procedure on the DB)?

I am working in C# with SQL Server.

Comment: Any changes made by a single UPDATE statement are atomic even if they affect multiple rows. You can write a WHERE clause to restrict the update to just the rows you want to update. Is there an issue writing a single UPDATE statement? How do you choose the records to update?

Comment: I am storing a tree structure in one of the tables and I need to make a chain updates from a node down to the root of the tree. I have a column that references the same table by RowID (I know that this is not optimal structuring for trees, but that is not important now). I can execute a single update and I know that is atomic, but my question was what would be the best way (and how would I make an atomic increment using LINQ to SQL).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What if he is executing mutiple update statements ??

Comment: If you do the changes and do one `SubmitChanges` call everything happens in one transaction. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: That's true, but if you increment a value and then submit this will not submit as increment, but as the new value, meaning it will not provide atomicity of the increment operation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer: The increment cannot be realized through LINQ to SQL directly. However, stored procedures can be called from LINQ, and increment can be realized there.

My solution was to create a stored procedure that would execute necessary updates within a single while loop in a transaction. This way all the updates are executed as a single, atomic, operation.

The UPDATE statement is atomic by itself.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server Atomicity between different operations is achieved by using `Explicit Transactions`, Where the user Explicitly Starts a transaction by using the key words `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and once all the operations are done without any erros you can commit the transaction by using key words `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, in case of an error/exception you can undo the work anywhere in the ongoing transaction by using key words `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`
**Write Ahead Strategy**
SQL server uses `Write Ahead Strategy` to make sure the atomicity of the transactions and durability of data, When we are making any changes/Updates to the data, SQL Server takes following steps

1. Loads data pages into a buffer cache.
2. Updates the copy in the buffer.
3. Creates a log record in a log cache.
4. Saves the log record to disk via the checkpoint process.
5. Saves the data to disk.

So anywhere in the process of all these steps if you decide to ROLLBACK the transaction. Your is actual data on the disk is left unchanged.
**My Suggestion**

```
BEGIN TRY

       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        ------ Your Code Here ------


        ---- IF everything Goes fine (No errors/No Exceptions)

       COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 

         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   --< this will ROLLBACK any half done operations 


         -- Your Code here ---------

END CATCH
```

Comment: Transactions are needed only if you need to isolate multiple statements. A single UPDATE doesn't need an explicit transaction. I don't see how all this relates to the question

Comment: "I need to update several rows of one of my tables as an atomic operation." this is the very 1st line from this question, WRAPING multiple update in one explicit BEGIN TRAN ---- COMMIT TRAN will address the issue he is asking help for. Does it seem to relate to this question now ???  All Updates commited or none :)

Comment: No. He is asking for the statements, or the L2S calls